# GLSL global variables

Tags: opengl, glsl, global, shader

GLSL has many global variables that are predefined such as `gl_LightSource`. They are global because **any** shader can access them.

How do I define custom global variables in GLSL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Global variables don't exist in GLSL. The `gl_*` variables are hardcoded variables (**think of them as automatically added compile-time**) to access non-programmable elements of the pipeline from a shader. In Core OpenGL 3.0 most of them were removed, including `gl_LightSource`. The user is now expected to handle his own matrices and lights and send them to the shaders as uniforms. If you want to see a list of all the ones that remain, you should look at the [GLSL Reference Pages](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/).

What you want are uniforms. If you want to synchronize uniforms between shaders, store the location of the uniform and iterate through all your programs to upload the uniform to each shader.

Answer (score 6):

You can use uniform buffers. Here is a tutorial: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/uniform-blocks/

Answer (score 2):

Global shader variables in OpenGL are called "uniforms". They're read-only and can be bound with [`glUniformX`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glUniform.xml) calls. Roughly, it looks like this (this is more of a pseudocode):

```
// 1. activate the program
glUseProgram(program)

// 2. get uniform location
foo = glGetUniformLocation(program, "foo")

// 3. bind the value, e.g. a single float
glUniform1f(foo, 42.0)
```

Within the shaders, you need to qualify the variable with `uniform` storage qualifier, e.g.

```
uniform float foo;
```

Comment: But then what if program2 wants to access foo?

Comment: @KevinKostlan: Nothing stops you from using the same uniform in more than one program. Just follow the above procedure for every one.

Comment: I was hoping on having a camera matrix that I could do a glUniformX once and then every shader would have it (saves time). I guess that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

The usefulness of persistent variables is definitely something to aspire. OpenGL introduced instancing as part of the gl3, but was actually fully modeled in gl4. This answer's intent is to expand on the other answers as well as inform about instanced VBOs.

If you have access to gl4, you can keep an instanced VBO loaded with data that can change per draw (as opposed to per vertex) if its for something such as a tiled map. You can utilize the GLSL variable `gl_InstanceID` to detect which draw call you are on.

In the case of a tiled map, you use one model (probably 2 triangles aka 4 points, 4 texcoords, 6 indices to form a quad) to render a lot of tiles. You can update the values of said VBO easily cpu-side using normal gl buffer functions. The VBO can hold something like the tileid, which helps you calculate the texture coordinates indexing the tilesheet for the specified tile. The benefit is it updates per instance.

The typical use case of 'saving variables between draws' usually comes down to needing a counter, and `gl_InstanceID` definitely fits the bill. That is unless you need the GPU to do something that needs to be saved back.

If what you are after is calculating on the GPU, UBOs are a very nice way to get data to and from the GLSL shader. As @Arne suggested. However, there may be some way using other means to do what you are trying to do and they should be avoided in general use unless you actually use a lot of uniform variables.

If you are trying to define a constant variable, you can use the const keyword. However, this doesn't persist between shaders. Only the shader it is defined on.

```
const float example = 5.0;
```